Проблема с пуском на печать из браузера
Проблема в следующем, при пуске на печать любого документа из браузеров (любого) зависает на окне загрузка предварительного просмотра секунд на 40 при этом выбираеться принтер - сохранить как pdf. При этом по умолчанию в системе выбран физический принтер (Samsung m2020).
При этом с приложений типа word, foxit и т.д. печатает нормально.
Windows 11 Домашняя 23H2
Сброс браузура до настроек по умолчанию не помогает. Полное удаление тоже.
В какую сторону копать?

не уверен что сработает, но попробуй обновить драйвер принтера, или поменять браузер.

стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам стали доступны комментарии к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

на удивление действительно помогло переустановить драйвера.

я сам удивлен это много от чего помогает

Проблему не подтверждаю. Для Windows 11, v 10.0.26100.1301, как минимум. Уверен, что и в более-менее современных версиях, технически грамотно установленных, её нет. Проверял в Microsoft Edge, v 127.0.2651.98, и Google Chrome, v 127.0.6533.100.
Никаких принтеров по умолчанию даже и устанавливать не надо. В Windows можно легко использовать тот принтер, который был последним в использовании. Никто с такими данными о ковыряниях в ОС и её состоянии ничего реально не подскажет.
Решение:

Подготовиться к развёртыванию как следует (инсталляционный блок, винчестер, биос).
Весь софт в своём инсталляционном блоке обновить до максимально свежих версий.
Установить Windows по технологии вчистую.
Не ковыряться в ОС и не "удалять лишнее".
Не устанавливать обдолбанные "делатели из Windows 11 Windows XP". Они не сертифицированы и официально не поддерживаются МС, но могут серьёзно искалечить систему настроек.
Забыть словосочетание "групповые политики" - это только для специалистов (я, тем не менее, прекрасно обхожусь без этих ковыряний).
Сконфигурировать свои браузеры и убедиться, что никакой проблемы нет.
Продолжить развёртывание софта, на каждом шагу проверяя возможность правильной печати - для выявления возможного проблемного софта, влияющего таким образом на печать.

Обо мне - специализируюсь уже 30 лет на разгребании бардаков в экосистеме Microsoft и конфигурировании ПО на новых компах. С проблемами подобного рода разбираться - лишь время тратить. На современных компах переустановка всего софта вчистую занимает около 4 часов. Дольше комменты писать будете и ждать ответа.
